# No me compila scss con css

Tags: css, sass, scss, gulp

No me compila el scss con el css al momento de realizar cambios en scss no me lo muestra en css compilado,  al momento de arrancar el gulp watch me indica solo el Starting mas no el Finaled.. al momento de querer escribir en el scss y se compile en el css no se modifica para nada...¿Qué hago?

Answer (score 0):

Seria bueno que enseñes tu gulpfile,quizas algo hiciste mal , otra cosa muy rara que a mi me paso es que en mi archivo main.scss donde pongo todos import a compilar había escrito comentarios  con doble barra '//' para indicar  el nombre de los archivos y eso me causo un error(a pesar de que no se detectaba como tal), tuve que cambiar los comentarios  a ' /**/' y así fue como compiló , pero muestra tu gulpfile o tu main.scss ,el error debe estar ahí